# What does mixture refer to in LCMM and HLME in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution, latent-class

I am trying to use the HLME and LCMM functions to fit latent class mixed models to my data. Here are the documentations to both of them:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lcmm/versions/1.8.1.1/topics/hlme
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lcmm/versions/1.8.1.1/topics/lcmm

I understand what the `fixed` and `random` arguments refer to. But what does the `mixture` argument refer to? From the documentations, it is defined as "a one-sided formula object for the class-specific fixed effects in the latent process mixed model". However, i don't really understand it.

Does anyone understand what it is referring to?